# Using gApp Scripts in gDocs to move cursor to Selection and "Delete the next line"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have tried to delete certain paragraphs in the Header and Body Sections of a Google Doc using google apps scripts... however, if the paragraph is the last paragraph in a section there is an exception: *Can't remove the last paragraph in a document section.*

And yet that is the very paragraph I want to delete.

I have tried merging the paragraph with the previous paragraph but alas it does not work - the paragraph remains.

The only effective way of achieving this aim is to manually delete the paragraph by putting my cursor at the end of the previous line and pressing "forward" delete. This deletes the next line with no exceptions etc... however I need to automate this using apps script - so I am asking is there a way to search for an element in the script and then simulate pressing delete from that point? This is more of a hack but can't see another way of doing it?

An example might be:

```
var foundElement = body.findText("Dialogue");

while (foundElement != null) {
  // Get the text object from the element
  var foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText();

  // Where in the element is the found text?
  var start = foundElement.getStartOffset();
  var end = foundElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();  

 //PSUEDO CODE PRESS FORWARD DELETE TWICE FROM the **end** of the search phrase...
 end.pressdelete(twice)       
}
```

[image: Error Msg]
[image: Last Para inside Header]
[image: Delete Para inside table]
[image: First Para of Body and before table]

UPDATE:

I was able to delete the header paragraph by looping through all the headers in the doc - apparently, there can be more than one...

I am still stuck deleting the empty para in the table after Dialogue (screenshot 2)...

```
var p = d.getBody().getParent(); 
  var headers = [];
  var footers = [];
  // let's loop through all the child elements in the document including headers and footers etc...
  for ( var i = 0; i < p.getNumChildren(); i += 1 ) {
    var t = p.getChild(i).getType();
    if ( t === DocumentApp.ElementType.BODY_SECTION ) continue; // not interested in the body    
    if ( t === DocumentApp.ElementType.HEADER_SECTION ) {
      //OLD CODE FOR FIRST HEADER
      if (headers.length > -1) {
        headers.push(p.getChild(i).asHeaderSection())
      }      
      var h = p.getChild(i).asHeaderSection().getText();      
    } else if ( t === DocumentApp.ElementType.FOOTER_SECTION ) {
      var f = p.getChild(i).asFooterSection().getText();      
    }
  } 


  function cleanHeaders(p) {

    p.forEach(function(h, j, ar) {

      var para = h.getParagraphs();

      para.forEach(function(e, i, arr) {
        var children = e.getNumChildren()
        //Logger.log("::Children:: " + children);
        if (children < 1) {
          var t = e.getText();
          var type = e.getType();      
          var parent = e.getParent();
          var pChildren = parent.getNumChildren();
          var childIndex = parent.getChildIndex(e);
          //Logger.log("::Element::" + e + " ::Number:: " + i + " ::Type:: " + type + " ::Text:: " + t + " ::Children:: " + children + " ::Parent:: " + parent + " ::ParentChildren:: " + pChildren + " ::childIndex:: " + childIndex);

          for ( var i = 0; i < parent.getNumChildren(); i += 1 ) {
            Logger.log(parent.getChild(i));
            if (i != 0) {
              parent.getChild(i).asParagraph().merge();
            }
          } 

          if (parent != 'DocumentBodySection' && parent != 'HeaderSection') {
            //e.getPreviousSibling().merge();
          }          
        }        
      });       
    });
  }

  Logger.log("HEADERS: " + headers.length);  
  cleanHeaders(headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### As a workaround to `Can't remove the last paragraph`, you can insert an additional dummy paragraph

Sample:

```
function myFunction() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.appendParagraph('');
  var foundElement = body.findText("TargetText at end of line");
  while (foundElement != null) {
    var foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText();
    var paragraph = foundText.getParent();
    paragraph.removeFromParent();
    foundElement = body.findText("TargetText at end of line");    
  }
}
```

### UPDATE

If you want to deleter the last paragraph of multiples sections, you can implement an `catch..try` statement:

```
function myFunction() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var foundElement = body.findText("TargetText at end of line");
  while (foundElement != null) {
    var foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText();
    var paragraph = foundText.getParent();
    var parent = paragraph.getParent();
    try{
      paragraph.removeFromParent();
    }catch(err){
      body.appendParagraph('');
    }
    foundElement = body.findText("TargetText at end of line");    
  }
}
```

### UPDATE

To delete paragraphs following `foundElement` both i the the header and body, including tables you can use the following code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var foundElement = body.findText("TargetText at end of line");
  while (foundElement != null) {
    var foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText();
    var paragraph = foundText.getParent();
    var nextParagraph = paragraph.getNextSibling();
    var parent = paragraph.getParent();
    if(nextParagraph!= null && nextParagraph.getType()=="PARAGRAPH"){
      try{
        nextParagraph.removeFromParent();
      }catch(err){
        var dummyParagraph = body.appendParagraph('');
        nextParagraph.removeFromParent();
        dummyParagraph.merge();
      }
    }
    foundElement = body.findText("TargetText at end of line", foundElement);    
  }

  var header = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getHeader();
  foundElement = header.findText("TargetText at end of line");
  while (foundElement != null) {
    var foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText();
    var paragraph = foundText.getParent();
    var nextParagraph = paragraph.getNextSibling();
    var parent = paragraph.getParent();
    if(nextParagraph!= null && nextParagraph.getType()=="PARAGRAPH"){
      Logger.log(nextParagraph.asText().getText());
      try{
        nextParagraph.removeFromParent();
      }catch(err){
        var dummyParagraph = header.appendParagraph('');
        nextParagraph.removeFromParent();
        dummyParagraph.merge();
      }
    }
    foundElement = header.findText("TargetText at end of line", foundElement);    
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka - but sadly that does not address the issue, perhaps I was not clear enough. There are a number of places in a google doc where it is not possible to delete the last paragraph in a section without getting an exception saying that you cannot delete the last paragraph in a section. This solution does not fix it hence the workaround I suggested.

Comment: I see, in this case you can modify the workaround with appending empty paragraphs by iimplementing a try-catch statement during each iteration, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again @ziganotschka, however, your code actually deletes the "searched" text as well as the last paragraph that needs deleting.

Comment: Then I think I misunderstood your question. You do not want to delete the paragraph that contains a certain text, but the following one? What if the paragraph containing the text is the last tone of a section? Do you then want to delete the first paragraph of the next section?

Comment: Yes, I want to delete the empty paragraphs that the google doc seems to create. I have managed to delete the header paragraph at the end of the section... but now I am stuck trying to delete the para in the table (after the "Dialogue" text - see screenshot 2)... The main issue with the headers was that there were three headers in the document!

Comment: I hope now I understood your issue correctly and updated my answer. The code should work, just in case you have more than one header, you might need to modify it accordingly.

Comment: Hey @ziganotschka - thanks again! Your code works but it did not work in my case because I had previously deleted some bookmarks and that somehow - made things a bit wierd... So shall mark your answer as correct as it does work in a basic case scenario :) Many thanks.